# How should I pass three arguments to an express/node arrow function?

Tags: node.js, express, arrow-functions

I am declaring my function like this:

```
const parseConnections = (connectionsCSVPath, req, res) => { 
     //do a bunch of stuff 
}
```

Inside the function, if I try to call res.locals.something, I get an error saying "cannot read property locals of undefined" I have tried several other syntaxes, such as this:

```
const parseConnections = ((connectionsCSVPath, req, res) => { 
     //do a bunch of stuff 
})
```

this:

```
const parseConnections = (connectionsCSVPath, (req, res) => { 
     //do a bunch of stuff 
})
```

and this:

```
const parseConnections = connectionsCSVPath, (req, res) => { 
     //do a bunch of stuff 
}
```

and they all throw errors. What is the proper way to pass these 3 arguments to the function so that all 3 are defined inside?

Edit*: The function is then called like this:

```
router.post(
'/upload/engagements/batch', checkIfAuthenticated,
parseConnections('./tmp/connections.csv'), 
parseMessages('./tmp/messages.csv'), (req, res) => { 
    //do a bunch of stuff 
}
```

Comment: The last two are not doing what you think they do. How to define your function depends on how it is used. Please [edit] your question to include how the function is called (or where it is passed to). *"How should I pass three arguments to an express/node arrow function?"* The question is probably phrased incorrectly. If you are passing the function to express, then it's the framework that calls the function and passes arguments and you cannot influence how is called. However, you pass a function that calls `parseConnections` instead, but to provide a useful answer, we need to have more context

Comment: Ok I did that  ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not (necessarily) with how you define the function but with how you are using it.

`parseConnections('./tmp/connections.csv')` calls the function right then and there. You are only passing a single argument to it, so `req` and `res` will be `undefined`.

```js
function foo(a, b, c) {
  console.log('a:', a);
  console.log('b:', b);
  console.log('c:', c);
}

foo('first argument');
```

However, *you* cannot pass values for `req` and `res` because these values are created and passed by express itself.

Essentially you are making the mistake of *calling* a function where you should be *passing* it. [`router.post` expects to be passed one or more functions](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.METHOD). But you are *calling* `parseConnections` and pass its return value instead which is probably `undefined`.

Here is a simple example that demonstrates the difference:

```js
function foo(x) {
  console.log('inside foo', 'x is ', x);
}

// bar expects to be passed a function that it can call
function bar(callback) {
  console.log('bar received:', callback);
  try {
    callback(42);
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}


// this will work as expected
console.log('Passing a function');
bar(foo); 

// this will error because `bar` doesn't receive a function.
// this is what you are doing
console.log('Calling a function and passing its return value');
bar(foo(21));
```

---

One way to fix your problem is to make `parseConnections` *return a function*, which is then received by `router.post`. I'm using normal function declarations here so that the syntax is not too confusing:

```
function parseConnections(connectionsCSVPath) {
  return function(req, res) {
     //do a bunch of stuff 
  };
}
```

This requires no changes to your `router.post` call.

---

Another solution is to pass a function to `router.post` that calls `parseConnections` instead, passing along `req` and `res`:

```
router.post(
  '/upload/engagements/batch',
  checkIfAuthenticated,
  (req, res) => parseConnections('./tmp/connections.csv', req, res),
  // alternatively you can use `.bind`:
  // parseConnections.bind(null, './tmp/connections.csv'),
  parseMessages('./tmp/messages.csv'), // <- this is likely wrong as well,
                                       // but I leave this to you to figure out
  (req, res) => { 
    //do a bunch of stuff 
  }
);
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks! So if checkIfAuthenticated and parseMessages are also functions that need to take req and res, if I am understanding correctly, I would be left with something like this: `router.post(
    '/upload/engagements/batch', (checkIfAuthenticated, req, res),
    parseConnections('./tmp/connections.csv', req, res),
    parseMessages('./tmp/messages.csv', req, res), (req, res) => {`, but that also throws an error?

Comment: No, that's not valid. The way you pass `checkIfAuthenticated` in your original code was fine. I assume it is defined to only expect `req, res`, so you can pass it directly. You also forgot to actually wrap the `parseConnections` and `parseMessages` calls into functions (note the `(req, res) =>` in my answer and in the following example):
`router.post( '/upload/engagements/batch', checkIfAuthenticated, (req, res) => parseConnections('./tmp/connections.csv', req, res), (req, res) => parseMessages('./tmp/messages.csv', req, res), (req, res) => {...})`